# variables inside php include

Tags: php, include

Hello so I can’t get the includes to work with my site url variab so that would be `$IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl'];` it won’t work so the header, nav & footer wont show because its in the include. What im I doing wrong. So for not explaning well.

P.S It displays if I do `<?php echo $IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl']; ?>` as long as I am outside the other PHP tags. So does that mean you can use PHP tags inside the other PHP tags? If so is what I am trying to do possible?

index.php

```
<?php
$IN_LIONIMAGES = include('config.php');
?>

<?php include_once $IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl'] .'/inc/header.inc.php'; ?>
<?php include_once $IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl'] .'/inc/nav.inc.php'; ?>

<body>


    <section class="hero">
        <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo URLpath; ?>/theme/<?php echo THEME; ?>/img/hero.jpg);"></div>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <h3></h3>
        <a href="new.php" class="btn">Upload a Image</a>
    </section>


<?php include_once $IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl'] .'/inc/footer.inc.php'; ?>
```

config.php

```
    <?php
return [
    'siteurl' => 'http://sitename.com/',
];
?>
```

error_log

```
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 15
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(http://lionimages.dnt5.com/demo/inc/header.inc.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 15
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'http://lionimages.dnt5.com/demo/inc/header.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 15
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 16
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(http://lionimages.dnt5.com/demo/inc/nav.inc.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 16
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'http://lionimages.dnt5.com/demo/inc/nav.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 16
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 29
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(http://lionimages.dnt5.com/demo/inc/footer.inc.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 29
[01-Nov-2017 21:13:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'http://lionimages.dnt5.com/demo/inc/footer.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/lionimag/public_html/demo/index.php on line 29
```

Comment: `include_once('.$IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl'].'"/inc/header.inc.php");` should be `include_once($IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl'] . "/inc/header.inc.php");`. If you wrap a variable inside a single quoted string, it will use the string literally.

Comment: What is inside your "config.php" file?  if all that does is holds the state of that variable, you should just set the variable there and include the file.

Comment: Going to have other stuff in tge config.php file just focusing on one thing.

Comment: @durbnpoisn The OP have included the contents of config.php in the question.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson It won’t work. The include code you gave me doesnt work.

Comment: Btw, are you really going to include urls? Aren't those files on the same server? As long as the resulting path is a valid path, my example should work. A note, you're ending the `siteurl` with a slash and then have another slash in the beginning of the string your concatenating it with, so the path will have a double slash in there.

Comment: Good question @MagnusEriksson ... using urls is an awful lot of overhead if those files are all local!

Comment: You keep saying that things _"don't work"_. In what way? Do you get any error messages? Do you have `display_errors` enabled in your php.ini? Checked your servers error log? My guess is that you either don't have `allow_url_include` enabled in your php.ini (which is required to be able to include url's) or that the link simply is invalid.

Comment: None. For example I just changed the includes to `<?php include_once $IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl'] .'/inc/header.inc.php'; ?>` and it should display the page style and stuff because the css is inclued in the header and the page ONLY displays text.

Comment: So... have you checked the error log? Remember that if you do an include on a URL, none of the variables in those files will exist in your script. Including URL's will make the web server parse the PHP and just return the result for you to include, just like it would for a browser. I feel that we're not getting any further without more info, like the servers error log, if the files really should be included through URL's etc.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Error log added see updated post. ^^

Comment: That's what I mentioned in a previous comment: `allow_url_include=0`. Including URL's are disabled in your php.ini

Comment: But it works if I do `<?php include_once('inc/header.inc.php'); ?>` (keep in mind this is what I want to do but with `$IN_LIONIMAGES['siteurl'] .`) so it is allowed. Should I contact my web host staff?

Comment: `'inc/header.inc.php'` is a local relative path. When you append `http://sitename.com` berore it, it becomes a URL, which tells PHP to make a HTTP Request, hit the web server which will render that file and return the response. That's what's disabled and an expensive operation. So that's two totally different things. If the first (without `http://sitename.com`) works, just do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to say:

```
$IN_LIONIMAGES = Array('siteurl' => 'http://sitename.com/');
```

then it should work as you expect. You can put this inside the config.php file if you like

Comment: Since the included file contains a `return`, the OP's version works just as well.

Comment: Indeed - was considering deleting my response since you found the real issue. I found the posted code confusing and pointless though :-)

Comment: Yeah, his return of an array in the config to assign from an include, really is not the way I would have gone about setting up a config variable. It certainly is a bit odd, but then different people different coding techniques! His real problem was just the mangling of the quotes.

Comment: @Randall I prefer returning an array like that if it only contain things like settings.Then it's up to the includer to decide what variable it should be stored in. I think it's woese when you include a file that sets their own variables, where it isn't needed. More risk of overwritten variables and so on. But yes, that's just my opinion and a bit off topic. :-)